# What MySQL LIKE wildcard should I use to return someone's name without their title/prefix name?

Tags: sql, wildcard

I want to return name of customers and order them, but their titles must be excluded in ordering.

```
SELECT name
FROM customers
WHERE name LIKE ...
ORDER BY name
```

I mean by 'their titles' is such as Dr., Sn., Lady, Sir, Mr., and Mrs.

Comment: What do you mean by "their titles"

Comment: Adding clear and concise sample data would be the fastest way to get help here with your question.

Comment: Can you provide data on your question?

Comment: Their titles such as Dr., Sn., Ir., Lady,

Comment: Sorry I am not English native speaker

Comment: maybe show some column and data?

Comment: No real table actually

Comment: It doesn't seem so hard to create a table - just for an example. This is important, because, for example, it's still unclear from your question, where the titles can appear in the name column: obviously, there can be values like Mr Smith. But can it be Mr Adam Smith? Can it be something not allowed in English yet not contradicting the current question statement, like Adam Mr Smith? Of course, I think, you'd mention it if something strange could be there, but providing (an) example(s) is a good practice for a reason

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution to your problem.

In `Oracle`:

```
regexp_replace(user_name, '^(MISS|MS\.|MS|MRS\.|MRS|MR\.|MR)\s*', '') as user_name
```

Also you can use REPLACE () function like:

```
REPLACE (user_name, 'MISS', '') as user_name
```

If you have a column structure like (mr | mrs | other) / space / username you can try this:

```
with users(user_name) as 
              (select 'mr user name1' from dual union all 
               select 'miss username2 ' from dual union all
               select 'other username 3' from dual )

select substr(user_name,instr(user_name,' ')+1) real_username from users
```

Output:

```
REAL_USERNAME  
----------------
username 1       
username 2        
username 3
```

In `MSSQL`:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500)='Mr Sam'

SELECT Title,
       first_name,
       Substring(NAME, CASE
                         WHEN Charindex(' ', NAME) = 0 THEN 1
                         ELSE Charindex(' ', NAME)
                       END, Len(NAME)) last_name
FROM   (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN LEFT(@str, Charindex(' ', @str)) IN( 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss' ) THEN LEFT(@str, Charindex(' ', @str))
                 ELSE ''
               END AS Title,
               CASE
                 WHEN LEFT(@str, Charindex(' ', @str)) IN ( 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss' ) THEN LEFT(Stuff(@str, 1, Charindex(' ', @str), ''), Charindex(' ', Stuff(@str, 1, Charindex(' ', @str), '')))
                 ELSE LEFT(@str, Charindex(' ', @str))
               END AS first_name,
               CASE
                 WHEN LEFT(@str, Charindex(' ', @str)) IN ( 'Mr', 'Mrs', 'Miss' ) THEN Stuff(@str, 1, Charindex(' ', @str), '')
                 ELSE @str
               END NAME) a
```

Comment: I would like to use REPLACE() function but it is not allowed.

Comment: Why not use regexp?

Comment: Why REPLACE () is not allowed? Is this an ora error?

Comment: No, this is a practice from my lecturer

Comment: Then I think your teacher wants you to use regexp. Have you tried?

Comment: This is the task: Display customer names and sort the results by `customer_name` column by ascending (A to Z), however 'titles' should not be part of the order. Example: Ir. Agus Nugraha must be above Heidi Goh.

'Ir.' is the title.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231095/discussion-between-tdmns-and-joseph-armando-carvallo).

Answer (score 0):

Technically using a `%` before their name will allow any prefix, which would get you the desired result (ex. `WHERE name LIKE ('%' + @name)`. However, this is not the recommended approach on larger data sets as you will see significant performance issues with this approach.

Comment: There is only one customer with 'title' in his name. A customer with name "Ir. Ita Nugraha". 'Ir.' in his name is a title that I have to exclude from ordering customer name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific. First of all: Which SQL "flavor" are you using? Postgres? Oracle? MySql? This is very important because each engine has different functions. Every time you ask an SQL question in SO, be sure to include at the very least a tag mentioning which DBMS you're using.

Now, what do you mean by "I shouldn't return them". Do you mean you should not return records which have a prefix, or do you mean you need to return the records but without the prefix? (So if you have Dr. Henry Gutierrez, do you exclude him from the result? Or have it output as Henry Gutierrez?)

This is also a good place for another tip: Always write an expected output in your questions. "If X is Y then I expect the output to be this:"

If you need to exclude them entirely, you can use a REGEXP match (Once again, I cannot list a specific function because I have no idea which type of SQL you're using) Something like `WHERE REGEXP(UPPER(COL)) NOT ('^(MS|MR)\s+.*$')`

If it's the 2nd case, that's going to be much harder because you'd need to get a substring which excludes the prefix, but the prefixes all have different sizes so you can't just write a "one size fits all"

In general, it's a bad normalization practice to have prefixes in your SQL database. You should have a column called `PREFIX` and another column for the name itself.

EDIT: Based on your answer. This is the closest you can get to achieving what you want.

```
    SELECT NAME
    FROM (SELECT NAME, 
CASE WHEN NAME LIKE 'MR %' THEN SUBSTRING(NAME, 4) 
WHEN NAME LIKE 'MRS %' THEN SUBSTRING(NAME, 5) 
ELSE NAME AS NAME2 
FROM YOUR_TABLE ORDER BY NAME2) AS SUBQ
```

I am 99% sure this will not return the results ordered though, because the select order might be ignored outside of the subquery, so you can also just try whats in the subquery in a main query instead, but this will output 2 columns.

***My reply is in pseudocode. It is not exactly MySql syntax, you will need to check MySql documentation for the actual substring function implementation it has and for the `CASE` syntax.

Comment: The task is: Display customer names and sort the results by customer_name column by ascending (A to Z), however 'titles' should not be part of the order. Example: Ir. Agus Nugraha must be above Heidi Goh. 'Ir.' is the title.

Comment: I use mySQL for this

Comment: And this is a university task? This is not possible straight up with MySql or any type of SQL. SQL can only order by a column present in the query, and a column cannot have more than 1 sort order. The closest you could get to doing this would be to output a 2nd column using a CASE statement to create a substring excluding the prefix, or the original value if there's no prefix present, then order by that column.

Comment: And this would output 2 columns, with essentially the same info. I guess you could try doing this in a subquery and then just selecting the name column in the main one, but I don't think it's guaranteed that the columns will be pulled in the order they were in in the subquery.